# Jquery Json Cordova issue

Tags: jquery, json, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I'm having trouble with the following function. The purpose is to get data from a Json feed and add it to an offline database with jquery mobile. The database part works fine. The json part gets the data fine but can't add it to the database for some reason.

Could it be that the tx.executable method is not available from within the json function? If so, how do I get around this?

any ideas really appreciated!

```
function SyncDataQuery(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Picato');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Picato (id unique, date date,am_pm)');

    //code to get Json data from server.

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url1 2 3',  //fake url.
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){

        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            var insId = parseInt(item.idservice);
            var insDate = item.date;
            var insTime = item.am_pm;
            //alert(insId + insDate + insTime);
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Picato (id, date, am_pm) VALUES (insId, insDate,insTime)');
        });

    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
}); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `tx` object cannot be used to execute SQL statements in your `$.ajax` callback since the database transaction is finished before the `$.ajax` callback is run. You will encounter the same problem if you attempt this on a Web SQL database object.

The solution is to do run the transaction within the `$.ajax` callback. Here is how I would rework the code (in case of using the Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin):

```
// @param db - should be your database object
function SyncDataQuery(db) {
  db.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Picato');
  db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Picato (id unique, date date,am_pm)');

  //code to get Json data from server.

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://url1 2 3',  //fake url.
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status) {
      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        $.each(data, function(i,item) {
          var insId = parseInt(item.idservice);
          var insDate = item.date;
          var insTime = item.am_pm;
          //alert(insId + insDate + insTime);
          tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Picato (id, date, am_pm) VALUES (insId, insDate,insTime)');
       });
     });

    },
    error: function(){
      console.log('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
  }); 

}
```

Note that this code does not include any database error checking.

In case you use something other than the Cordova-sqlite-storage plugin, you may need to open a new transaction to DROP and CREATE the `Picato` table.

**UPDATE:** I just published a blog post to describe the solution along with sample code and a sample project at: http://www.brodybits.com/cordova/sqlite/api/jquery/2015/10/26/populating-cordova-sqlite-storage-with-the-jquery-api.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however it still didn't work. everything else is working. Its just the tx.executesql line in the loop that seems to be failing but I don't know why. Any other ideas?

Comment: seems the db.transaction still doesn't work within the $.ajax callback

Comment: I suggest you post a complete, self-contained test program that can demonstrate the issue. In addition, I suggest you try it with Web SQL first. If you get the same problem with Web SQL more people will be able to help you.

Comment: @JeremyWalmsley please take a look at https://github.com/brodybits/cordova-sqlite-ajax-demo - it is a full demonstration of how you can use JSON from JQuery AJAX together with the Cordova-sqite-storage plugin. Please let me know if you find it helpful and I am happy to update my answer. I am planning to document this when I get a chance to help others.